# create drop down menu from loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a php loop to generate a drop down menu via jquery with the following

```
  <script type="text/javascript">    
$(function(){
    // BUTTONS
    $('.fg-button').hover(
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default').addClass('ui-state-focus'); },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus').addClass('ui-state-default'); }
    );

    // MENUS        
    $('#flat').menu({ 
        content: $('#flat').next().html(), // grab content from this page
        showSpeed: 400 
    });

    $('#hierarchy').menu({
        content: $('#hierarchy').next().html(),
        crumbDefaultText: ' '
    });
    var n = <?php echo $x; ?>

    $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).menu({
        content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
        backLink: false
    });


    // or from an external source
    $.get('menuContent.html', function(data){ // grab content from another page
        $('#flyout').menu({ content: data, flyOut: true });
    });
});
 </script>


 <?php
 for($x=0;$x<2;$x++)
 {
     ?>
 <a tabindex="0" href="#news-items-2" class="fg-button fg-button-icon-right ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="hierarchybreadcrumb<?php echo $x;?>"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Settings</a>

 <div id="news-items-2" class="hidden">
 <ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo $x;?>">View Details</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>


  </ul>
 </div>
```

The problem I am having is with this

```
var n = <?php echo $x; ?>

$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).menu({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
});
```

If I manually enter the value for n, all is good. I get the 2 drop down menus generated.

```
$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + 0).menu({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
});

$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + 1).menu({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
});
```

How can I get the $x variable in PHP to work in the script?

Comment: You need to loop inside the JS as well, so you can reuse x as `var x = $x; for n = 0; n < $x; ....`.

Comment: Where do you define the PHP variable?

Comment: Thanks but something is still nto right. Even if I do 

var n = 1

$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).menu({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
});

The menu doesn't work. Meaning, the button is there but the drop down action isn;t working

Comment: Islam - I define the php var in the php section. I'm a JS and JQ peasant so not sure if I am declaring the $x in the JQ properly

Comment: The whole file is a `.php` right?

Comment: If you var_dump $x, is the number correct? It's bad practice to use $x as a variable and as a counter for your loop.

Comment: Islam - yes the whole file is PHP ----- 
Wimanicesir - var dump $x is giving me the correct values

Comment: Maybe try var n = <?php echo json_encode($x); ?>;

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around the the value generated by $x, as it would be string in nature

```
var n = '<?php echo $x; ?>';
```

Then bind the variable "n" to the container for your drop down.

```
$('menuContainerSelector').html(n)
```

Comment: Like this?


var n = '<?php echo $x; ?>';
$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).menu({
 $('menuContainerSelector').html(n),
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
});

Comment: @Gino , you have mentioned that it was working when you put the data manually?
can you post the data (value for $x) that is working for you.?

Comment: This works ---- 
$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + 0).menu({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
}); ------------ This does not work ----- 
var n = 0
$('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).menu({
    content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb' + n).next().html(),
    backLink: false
});

Comment: @Gino I think you are confused with the life cycle of php and javascript compilation. PHP code will execute on server and javascript code on browser. In short you can not loop php in javascript.

Comment: you can refer to static variable values not dynamic.